# Refrescar tabla cuando se actualiza un item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo este `Ajax`

```
$(function() {
    //function ajax
    $('.processPreset').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var checkedNames = '';
        var $things = $('.case:checked');
        if ($things.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $things.length; i++) {
                checkedNames += $($things[i]).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
                console.log(checkedNames);
            }

           $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/processPreset',
            method: 'post',
            data: { idArticulo: checkedNames },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
               // RefreshTable();
               //checkedNames += $($things[i]).closest('tr').find('td:first').remove();
            }
        });
        } else {
            alert('No tiene articulo seleccionado');
        }


    });

});
```

El cual lo que me hace es guardar un campo de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que cuando guarde, me quite el campo de la tabla, ya sea eliminando o refrescando la tabla

Comment: Codigo de tu llenado de tabla en JS?

Comment: ¿Quieres que después de guardar te vacíe la tabla? La manera rápida: `tbody.innerHTML = '';`. La manera eficiente: `while(tbody.firstChild) { tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstChild); }`.

Comment: No necesito limpiar toda la tabla, solo el item seleccionado.

Comment: Entonces solo te bastaría `$('.case:checked').eq(0).parent().parent().remove()`. Lo que se traduce a: *del checkbox seleccionado, selecciona su padre (td) y el padre de éste (tr) para finalmente eliminarlo*.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía muchas gracias, me sirvió.

Comment: Muevo mi comentario a respuesta para que la marques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo te basta seleccionar el checkbox que esté marcado, luego seleccionas al padre lejano que es el *tr* para finalmente aplicar [`remove`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
$('.case:checked').eq(0).parent().parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

De la misma forma que usas esto `$($things[i]).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();` para obtener el nombre, aplicale un `hide`, algo así `$($things[i]).closest('tr').hide()` si lo que quieres es solo dejar de mostrar la fila. Si quieres eliminarla `$($things[i]).closest('tr').remove()`

Comment: No funciona igual se queda en la tabla, ya lo intente.

Comment: Ya veo, será porque `$things[i]` es el check, eso debe cambiar por la referencia de tu tabla

Comment: Entonces lo cambio por checkedNames ?

Comment: Por la referencia de tu tabla `var tabla = $('#idTabla');`

Comment: Entonces quedaría de esta manera `var tabla = $('#example-table').closest('tr').remove();
`

Comment: Intenta y lo comentas si te sale o no.